# How do I space out the buttons in an array created?

Tags: ios, swift3

I want to make a popup menu which is a UIView containing an array of buttons which should be existing side by side. Instead, they are all stacked on top of each other despite my changing the center.x dynamically. This is my code snippet:

```
func createPopUpView(number: Int) -> UIView{
    let popUpView: UIView = UIView()
    var buttons: [UIButton] = [UIButton]()
    let button: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 32, height:42))
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    for i in 0..<number {
        buttons.append(button)
        buttons[i].setTitle(String(i), for: .normal)
        buttons[i].center.x += 32
        popUpView.addSubview(buttons[i])
    }       
    return popUpView        
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: `let button: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: i*32, y: 0, width: 32, height:42))` instead, and put it inside the `for` loop?

Comment: Are you *sure* the "buttons" are being *"stacked on top of each other"*? Spoiler: they are not. You only ever have 1 button. Just because you repeatedly append it to an array does not mean you are creating copies of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a new button each time through the loop. Also, need to supply a frame when you create your popUpView...

Try it like this:

```
func createPopUpView(number: Int) -> UIView{
    let popUpView: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: number * 32, height: 42))
    for i in 0..<number {
        let button: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: i * 32, y: 0, width: 32, height:42))
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        button.setTitle(String(i), for: .normal)
        popUpView.addSubview(button)
    }
    return popUpView
}
```